# WPF Binding to my own property

Tags: wpf, binding

I Created my own UserControl which has some a property which is calculated from something, lets call it  Result. Now, I want to place this this control on a Grid and I have some buisness object. I want to bind a property in this object to my property Result. So I make something like this:

```
<MyControl Result="{Binding PropertyInObject}" ...
```

Of course DataContext is set and binding of other properties (wpf properties) is working. But this one is not.
First it shoot an exception which says that I can't bind to non-dependency property. So I register it as one. Now it doesn't give exception but also doesn't get job done. So what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

1. You will have to make your Result property in your UserControl as Dependency Property.  This way you will be able to bind any value to this property.  Here is an example how to implement custom [Dependency Prooperty](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html)
2. In your business object you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to notify your Result property about any changes in your business object.  Here is an example how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged [PropertyChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and raise the PropertyChanged event after you make the calculation. Then bind the control by default (twoway) to your property.

I would recommend you this book for study: [Programming WPF.](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510374)